# Github: avoid syncing/pulling README.md

Tags: git, github, dotfiles

How can I exclude `README.md` from all sync/pull/push github requests?  I wish to download/sync all files *except* that file.

Context: I have a repo for [StreakyCobra style dotfiles management](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11070797).  I would like to add some notes to `README.md` (showing up on github), but wish to avoid having the file in `$HOME` on my computer.

Comment: You could do a sparse checkout, include everything and explicitly exclude README.md.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working off of @kba's comment, here's a solution that works:

You can enable sparse checkout for a repo with the following command: `git config core.sparsecheckout true`

Then edit the repository's `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file to be:

```
/*
!README.md
```

which essentially says "checkout everything, except any file named `README.md`". The format of `sparse-checkout` works the same as a `.gitignore` file.

Just tested this by checking out an existing repository, and it works. (Although, there's a catch-22 situation where you need an existing repository to configure the sparse checkout on, so I used `git init` to create one, configured it, and then added the existing repo as a new remote).

Answer (score -2):

you may use `.gitignore` file in which related file will be ignored by the git. An example is as belows:

```
README.md
# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea

# arcconfig
```

.arcconfig